# php pdo prepare statement dynamic filter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to use simple filter with pdo statement.  Previously I was using the below code.

```
$sql = "select * from cities where 1 ";
$city = $_REQUEST['city_name'];
if($city!=""){
   $sql = $sql. " and name ='".$city."'";

 } 
 $country = $_REQUEST['country_name'];
if($country!=""){
   $sql = $sql. " and country_name ='".$country."'";

 } 

$result= mysql_query($sql);
```

I want to use filter if name or country name does not come , it should display all result , If name is selected there only city name result will come. If country is selected then country will appply otherwise country filter will not apply.

Now I want to use same with pdo prepared statement but I am not getting how to create it.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: Why are you using `where 1`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @meagar i want to use filter according to condition so does not want to check every time where clause, If someone filter with country name then country filter will be applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this:**

```
    $arr = array();
    $sql = "select * from cities where 1 ";
    $city = $_REQUEST['city_name'];
    if($city!=""){
        $sql .= " and name = :name";
        $arr[] = ":name => $city";

    }
    $country = $_REQUEST['country_name'];
    if($country!=""){
        $sql .=  " and country_name = :country";
        $arr[] = ":country => $country"; 
    }
    $db = new PDO(DSN, user, password);//set correct db credential 
    $objStaement = $db->prepare($sql);
    //if ($city) $objStaement->bindValue(':name',$city);
    //if ($country) $objStaement->bindValue(':country',$country);
    $objStaement->execute($arr);
    $objStaement->closeCursor();
```

Comment: yes its seems working , but i have to  write 2 times if statement , first for creating query and second time for binding .. can it possible with 1 if ?

Comment: @nitin jain : is there any issues with two times if statement?

Comment: But for same condition i am writing 2 if statement. If i have many filters then i have to write filters*2 if blocks. It could be slow?

Comment: @nitin jain: can you try edited answer and let me know ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45171/discussion-between-nitin-jain-and-awlad-liton)

Comment: It should be `$arr[":name"] = $city;` and `$arr[":country"] = $country; `

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `$dynamic_fields` must contain mysql field names in keys and input names in values:

```
// mysql_fileld_name => request_key_name
$dynamic_fields = array(
    'name'         => 'city_name',
    'country_name' => 'country_name'
);
$field_values = array();
foreach ($dynamic_fields as $mysql_fname => $input_fname) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[ $input_fname ])) {
        $sql .= ' AND `' . $mysql_fname . '` = :' . $mysql_fname; 
        $field_values[ ':' . $mysql_fname ] = $_REQUEST[ $input_fname ];
    }
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($field_values);

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (special edit just for you)...now all binding is made within one long if/elseif statement. More code but perhaps a tiny tiny bit faster.

```
$name = $_REQUEST['city_name'];
$country_name = $_REQUEST['country_name'];

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db';
$db_user = 'username';
$db_password = 'password';


$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
if ($name && $country_name) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = :name AND country_name = :country_name';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $statement->bindValue(':country_name',$country_name);
} elseif ($name) { 
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = :name';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':name',$name);
} elseif ($country_name) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cities WHERE country_name = :country_name';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':country_name',$country_name);
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cities';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
}

$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
```

Comment: if there is no city name and country name then it will display all result ?

Comment: @nitinjain If there are no matches, no results will be fetched. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I want to use filter if name or country name does not come , it should display all result , If name is selected there only city name result will come. If country is selected then country will appply otherwise country filter will not apply.

Comment: @nitinjain Ok check my edit and see if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: @nitinjain elseifs make sure the rest of the arguments won't be evaluated when a match is found. Just because there is more text in the code doesn't mean it will take longer to execute.

Comment: @nitinjain However, I changed it now like you seem to want it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your query the same way. but to execute the query you use

```
$db = new PDO(your information...);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);<--your query is $sql
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //use this to get associative array
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //use this to get objects
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); //use this for a regular array
```

more information on fetch styles [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). You might want to learn about paramaterized queries as well [PDOStatement::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)